# Can I put parentheses inside a string?

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio, parentheses

I'm writing a script generator in Visual Studio and I've run across a problem.
This is my code:

```
Dim Text As String
Text = "Register.node("Play") {(speed = 0, Evnt=0,)}"
```

And the string doesn't cover it.. I don't know why it keeps exiting the string?
In all other languages I've used there is no way of exiting a string from inside.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either using double quotes...

```
Text = "Register.node(""Play"") {(speed = 0, Evnt=0,)}"
```

Or typing it thusly.

```
Text = 'Register.node("Play") {(speed = 0, Evnt=0,)}'
```

or maybe even like so.

```
Text = "Register.node("+"Play"+") {(speed = 0, Evnt=0,)}"
```

Comment: The second version does not work in VB.Net because the ' char indicates a comment.

Comment: Double quote is called an escape "some text ""hello"" "
 will output
some text "hello"